# Removing commmits from github repo history

Tags: git, github

I have a github repo shared with two people, have recently worked on the project and made commits (also pushed to the repo). Is it possible for me to remove the commits i made so that the others with acces to the repo have no acces to my progress anymore?

Comment: It is possible, but honestly you should not. And git is ment to never forget. So, please consider if you really want to do that. ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper well the thing is, we did a project together, i worked quite hard on it, they bailed. And i dont want them using my progress next year

Comment: I could say now, "search in SO and elsewhere, to find an answer". And there is definitely one which excatly does what you want. But honestly, knowing the background now, I would strongly discourage you to do this. Feel proud what you have done. It will not be the only code which you contribute to others. You definitele will feel better about it a couple years later ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper good advise, and i would agree if i would not have to do the course next year aswell. I'm going to reuse it, but if they do too, I would get in trouble for plagiarism.

Comment: You won't earn respect when you are trying to be mean. It's futile anyway, because your fellow peers have a copy locally anyway. Git exactly knows who has done what. Deleting the commit history might be detected and can make you rather suspicious. So, I strongly discourage you to do anything like this.

Comment: use `git rebase -i HEAD~number-of-commits` and mark each commit you want to delete as `d` or `drop` and push the changes to the repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the .git folder may cause problems in your git repository. If you want to delete all your commit history but keep the code in its current state

Checkout

```
git checkout --orphan latest_branch
```

Add all the files

```
git add -A
```

Commit the changes

```
git commit -am "commit message"
```

Delete the branch

```
git branch -D main
```

Rename the current branch to main

```
git branch -m main
```

Finally, force update your repository

```
git push -f origin main
```

Comment: can i also delete all commits that happened after a certain point?

Comment: they will still appear even throw if you delete the branch. if you try `git log` you will see all of the changes.